# CreateFileA trying to get the full string of lpFileName

Tags: c++, messagebox, createfile

```
HANDLE WINAPI f_CreateFileA(LPCSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, lpFileName, lpFileName, MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    return CreateFileA(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I'm trying to make my messagebox show the Filename that was passed to CreateFile and it is only showing "C" and i would assume it's because the special characters it has and i was wondering if someone could tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: `MessageBoxA` is quite happy with narrow code page strings. Try  putting a breakpoint on `MessageBoxA` and inspect the parameters passed. Suggest you start using the unicode functions if you think you have special characters, `MessageBoxW` and `CreateFileW` and switch to a full unicode build.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that there is nothing wrong with CreateFileA or MessageBoxA, but rather that the problem is that you're hooking the CreateFileW function by mistake.

Comment: Thank you guys your response helped and i was in fact hooking CreateFileW and have fixed the issue! I'm a bit new to C++ and i am playing around with hooks!